# Settings are inconsistent on whether descriptions end in periods or not

Tags: feature-request, grammar, preferences

On the user settings page (your Meta SE one is [here](/users/preferences/current)) the smaller-font descriptions sometimes end in periods and sometimes don't. [This guidance](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#periods) says "Don’t use periods in interface copy unless it’s a full sentence or description.", and while the non-period descriptions are indeed sentence fragments, they're still descriptions. Additionally, the way that these settings and descriptions are arranged similarly to each other means I think it would be nice if the periods were the same as well. Could it be standardized one way or another?

Here is a list of settings or setting-adjacent things from "Email Settings" or "Preferences"

| Name | Description | Has period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enable new editor | When you flip this switch, you will be opting into a beta test for our new text editor. | Yes |
| Enable keyboard shortcuts | When enabled, press `?` for help | No |
| Hide left navigation | When you flip this switch, the left navigation will no longer be pinned to the left of the page on Q&A sites. | Yes |
| Hide hot network questions | When you flip this switch, you will no longer see Hot Network Questions in the right sidebar on Q&A sites. | Yes |
| Enable advertisements | You have earned the [reduce ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) privilege. If you'd prefer, you can re-enable them here. | Yes |
| Stack Overflow never sells or shares your activity data with third parties. | We use your on-site activity to show you more relevant content. For example, we might show you questions based on the tags you usually browse, or show you job listings in your current location. | Yes |
| Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content (recommended) | If you opt-out, existing recommendations will be discarded within 24 hours. | Yes |
| Promotional | Get emails to find out what’s going on when you’re not on Stack Overflow. You can turn them off whenever you want. | Yes |
| Features & Announcements | New products and feature updates, as well as occasional company announcements | No |
| Promotional emails from other Stack Overflow systems | Stack Overflow maintains separate Sales and Marketing platforms for business-related emails to promote our paid products to potential business customers. Unsubscribing from all promotional emails using the toggle at the top of this section will sync your unsubscribe request with any matching email addresses in these systems. | Yes |
| Invitations | Invitations to participate in surveys, usability tests, and more. Only a few per year. | Yes |
| Tips & Reminders | Timely advice and reminders to help you make the most of our features | No |
| Inbox | Answers to your questions, comments, chat notifications, and more | No |
| Community Milestones | Notifications about bounties, reputation and more. Hint: sometimes involves swag. | Yes |
| Community Digests | Our best community content of the week | No |
| Question Subscriptions | New questions that match your criteria | No |
| Stop sending me tag notifications | We want to keep in touch, but only in ways that you find helpful. | Yes |
| Stop sending me community digests | We want to keep in touch, but only in ways that you find helpful. | Yes |